# JUnit @Category annotation with SpringRunner.class

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I followed [this blog post](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074569/core-java/unit-and-integration-tests-with-maven-and-junit-categories.html) to set up a Maven build with separate unit and integration tests, using the `@Category` annotation.

For the most part this works: tests marked as `@Category(IntegrationTest.class)` executes in the `integration-test` phase and all unmarked tests execute in the `test` phase.

However, it looks like the context for the integration tests are still being (partially?) created when the unit tests are run, even though the tests themselves aren't being run:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ bamboo ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: [removed]
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider
[INFO] parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=0, useUnlimitedThreads=false, threadCountSuites=0, threadCountClasses=0, threadCountMethods=0, parallelOptimized=true

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
09:56:05.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.example.MyIntegrationTest]
09:56:05.463 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
09:56:05.468 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
09:56:05.481 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
09:56:05.494 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
09:56:05.497 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]: class path resource [com/example/MyIntegrationTest-context.xml] does not exist
09:56:05.497 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]: class path resource [com/example/MyIntegrationTestContext.groovy] does not exist
09:56:05.497 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
09:56:05.530 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]
09:56:05.563 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]: using defaults.
09:56:05.567 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
09:56:05.580 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
09:56:05.586 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@62fdb4a6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@11e21d0e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@1dd02175, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@31206beb, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@3e77a1ed, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@3ffcd140, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@23bb8443, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1176dcec, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@120d6fe6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@4ba2ca36, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@3444d69d]
09:56:05.591 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]
09:56:05.591 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.example.MyIntegrationTest]
Running com.example.MyUnitTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.323 sec - in com.example.MyUnitTest
```

This is how `MyIntegrationTest` is annotated:

```
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApp.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private ActualObject actualObject;
}
```

How do I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Maybe evaluate moving the IT tests in a separate maven module.

Comment: @hovanessyan we did consider that, but for various reasons we decided not to go that route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a TestContext, but does not initialize it, so it should be fast.

For each test class a Spring TestContextManager is created, as defined in the constructor of SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java (same as SpringRunner.java).

I don't think you can avoid creation of the TestRunner, other than by actually excluding the Test file itself.

You can best suppress those logs by adding a `logback-test.xml` in you test/resources folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```